# Type error: next is not a function in Node js

Tags: node.js, algorithm

I am doing a hackerrank code challenge and I'm taking some problems with the test because I'm getting the next issue : next is not a function.

I'm trying to solve the generatorPrimerNumbers problem. I'm new in node js and I'm not pretty sure what is the cause of this issue, the code is the next:

```
   function getPrimes(n) {
    var sieve = [], i, j, primes = [];
    for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (!sieve[i]) {
            // i has not been marked -- it is prime
            primes.push(i);
            for (j = i << 1; j <= n; j += i) {
                sieve[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

This is the main code from hackerrank:

```
 main = () => {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

    const n = parseInt(readLine(), 10);

    let res = [];
    let gen = getPrimes(n);

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        let val = gen.next().value;
        if (val == undefined)
            break;
        res.push(val);
    }

    ws.write(res.join("\n") + "\n");

    ws.end();
}
```

The issue is presented in the line: `let val = gen.next().value;`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Succinctly, [a generator is an object which has a `next()` method](https://codeburst.io/understanding-generators-in-es6-javascript-with-examples-6728834016d5) you can call to get a value.

I guess the hackerrank test challeges you to implement a `getPrimes` methods that returns a generator (via the `yield`), so their given code can use it. That's why the challenge is called 'generatorPrimeNumbers'. The challenge is more about generators than prime numbers I guess.

Your problem is that your `getPrimes` implementation returns an array, not a generator. Arrays don't have any `next` function, so when the provided code calls:

```
let val = gen.next().value;
```

it throws an error.

Your method should use `yield` to return the following primer number, so `gen.next()` can get a prime, and be declared as a generator via the * character before function definition.

You should study generators a bit so you can implement the `getPrimes` properly and ace the challenge!

Answer (score 0):

The line `let val = gen.next().value;` means that gen is an iterable.
which means `function getPrimes(n) { ... }` should be a generator function.

the below code snippet should fix the issue.

```js
   function *getPrimes(n) {
    var sieve = [], i, j, primes = [];
    for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (!sieve[i]) {
            // i has not been marked -- it is prime
            // primes.push(i);
            yield i;
            for (j = i << 1; j <= n; j += i) {
                sieve[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

Please note the `*` (asterisk) sign before the function name and the `yield` keyword.

PS: Also, I haven't checked your logic for getting the prime number. so please focus only on the syntax

Comment: With this code I got the next error message:     /tmp/submission/20191210/15/31/hackerrank-f0b1d2618661300025f5460403169956/code/Solution.js:32
            yield i;                                          
 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at checkScriptSyntax (internal/bootstrap/node.js:619:5)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:280:11)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3. Maybe yield is not supported.

Comment: I doubt it since the problem statement itself says "generatorPrimerNumbers", so at least they will use a node version that supports it.

Comment: could you share the problem link of hacker-rank?